# Test variable value against multiple literals or variables

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6

Does javascript provide syntax sugar to compare variable to a set of literals and variables at once?

It's tedious to write `if (x !== foo || x !== bar)` and I would like to have sorter version like `if (<< x !== foo || bar >>)`

I know I could use switch statement but I'm looking for something inline and less verbose

Comment: Unless `x == foo == bar`, this condition is always true. Did you mean `(x !== foo && x !== bar)` ?

Comment: Why to state the obvious rather than answer the question? I want to return in the case x is neither. It's just a placeholder condition anyway

Comment: If 'sugar' is meant to make things look nicer, I don't think there is a better way. If its about fewest characters, it more of a codegolf.stackexchange.com question, so let the game begin...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if ([foo, bar].indexOf(x) === -1) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
![foo,bar].includes(x) && doSomething();
```

Comment: For those who need to support IE, this won't work without a polyfill :-(

Comment: @mcgraphix Yes right.. but there is `ecmascript-6` tag on the question so i thought it's worthwhile to give this solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own comparison function, here in ES6 syntax:

```js
function isNot(v, ...a) {
  return a.indexOf(v) == -1;
}

var x, foo = 123, bar = 456;

x = 456;
console.log(isNot(x, foo, bar));

x = 789;
console.log(isNot(x, foo, bar));
```

Or you could even create new prototype methods. For instance for Number:

```js
Number.prototype.notIn = function(...a) {
  return a.indexOf(this.valueOf()) == -1;
}

var x, foo = 123, bar = 456;

x = 456;
console.log(x.notIn(foo, bar));

x = 789;
console.log(x.notIn(foo, bar));
```

**NB**: You may want to use a `for` loop iterating on `arguments` for browsers not supporting ES6.

Comment: If you're using ES6 (`Array.from`), you might as well use `function isNot(v, ...a) {`

Comment: @loganfsmyth - Very true! Answer updated accordingly. Thanks!